# Eclipse application with javafx hangs

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-rcp, javafx-8

I've an eclipse E4 application with certain pieces of it implemented in JavaFx and the rest using SWT. The application hangs intermittently and here is the stack from jconsole.exe when the application hung on app launch.

```
Name: JavaFX Application Thread
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync@74205acd
Total blocked: 14  Total waited: 43

Stack trace: 
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PaintCollector.waitForRenderingToComplete(PaintCollector.java:157)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassScene.waitForRenderingToComplete(GlassScene.java:127)
javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2410)
com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$181/1142931081.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$51/889885902.run(Unknown Source)
org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:164)
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

I'm using Java8.

Comment: can you include your code too?

Comment: the code is too huge to be included here. I see this occur intermittently. Sometimes it hangs during app launch, while other times it hangs in the middle of an execution (no particular action causes it to hang). The stack trace looks exactly the same each time it hangs

Comment: It's difficult to determine why it is hanging with just a stack trace.

Comment: What operating system was this on?

Comment: Windows 7. My issue was a listener that was called frequently that it bogged down all resources. Removing it solved the issue.